# Insert Japanese char "" on a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert in a MySQL table a list of Japanese kanji.

I have insert more then 13000 kanji without errors but I have a problem with this char .

> "Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA0\x86\xA2' for column 'radicals' at row 66"

The char-set of the table is `utf8_unicode_ci`

I have imported the same list of kanji in an Access database without problem.

[Here's](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=201a2) the link of the char that I'm trying to insert

Comment: Show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the given table. PS: "The char-set of the table is utf8_unicode_ci" --- it's not a charset, but collation

Comment: That character is from the CJK extension area, which means it requires the 32-bit Unicode representation (4 bytes) to encode this character (notice the UTF-16 value is double-wide). If you're storing single characters, then it might be expecting a 16-bit value, which would cause the problem.

Comment: @DaoWen: "If you're storing single characters, then it might be expecting a 16-bit value, which would cause the problem" --- what does it mean?

Comment: @zerkms - Yeah, that wasn't worded clearly. I meant that if _radicals_ is a single-character field in the table, it might be hard-coded to 16 bits (since that's the typical unicode character width). Storing a double-wide character would cause an error in this case since it doesn't fit in 16 bits.

Comment: here the table:
CREATE TABLE `kradfile-u` (
 `kanji` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `radicals` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci    how should i change it? :o sorry i'm a bit noob

Comment: @DaoWen: "if radicals is a single-character field in the table" --- then nothing will happen - mysql will treat a string as a stream of bytes and will store it as is

Comment: @zerkms - My point was that if the table only allocated 2 bytes to store the radical, that would be a potential problem since this character requires 4 bytes—but that was just a stab in the dark and I was obviously wrong with that guess. I'm glad xdazz knew that "utf8" doesn't actually support the full utf8 spec.

Answer (score 5):

is a 4 byte char, to support such char, you need to use  **[the utf8mb4 Character Set (4-Byte UTF-8 Unicode Encoding)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)**, otherwise you can't insert it.

Comment: Oh, it wouldn't be mysql if it didn't have some terribly unexpected type/behaviour

Comment: I knew it had something to do with this being a CJK supplemental character! +1 for actually providing the right character set to use.

Comment: Solved, Thanks to everyone, i forgot to change also the Connection Character Sets of the DB to utf8mb4